# Android - RecyclerView starts in the middle instead of the top

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

There are several related posts here, but none are quite the same situation/none of the solutions have worked for me.

I have a RecyclerView that loads in some data from Firebase. I'm using a custom adapter. The issue is that when the view loads in, it loads in at the middle of the RecyclerView. I then would have to scroll up to the top manually.

My layout is very simple:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@color/grey"
          android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
          >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_feed"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
```

After loading in my custom objects from Firebase, I set up the RecyclerView like this (this is in a method being called from onCreateView (it's a fragment)):

```
CompleteWorkoutRecyclerAdapter adapter = new CompleteWorkoutRecyclerAdapter(list, getContext(),
                                getActivity());
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

I've tried these things to fix the issue, with no luck:

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
```

and

```
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
```

and

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Thanks for reading. If you guys need any more code I can post whatever you need

Comment: what is the size of list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your xml to this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_feed"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
```

then the code to

```
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
CompleteWorkoutRecyclerAdapter adapter = new CompleteWorkoutRecyclerAdapter(list, getContext(),
                                getActivity());
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Change height of your row layout in your adapter to wrap_content

Comment: Thanks so much, this fixed it. I guess it has something to do with the order in which you call the layout manager/adapter?

Comment: You should never use `wrap_content` in a RecyclerVIew, this is a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
      CompleteWorkoutRecyclerAdapter adapter = new CompleteWorkoutRecyclerAdapter(list, getContext(),
                                    getActivity());

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this will help you out..

Answer (score 0):

Use `relative layout` instead of `linear layout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/grey"
          android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
          >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_feed"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found that the layout for a row in my recycler view has layout_height set as `match_parent`, causing it to fill up the whole parent view. I fixed it by using `wrap_content` instead (or maybe set a fixed height would work too)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```